Как верстать блок необычной формы адаптивно?
В макете есть вот такой блок необычной формы с вырезом. Не могу понять каким образом его можна сверстать адаптивно, чтобы он подстраивался под содержимое по высоте и при этом не терял пропорции сверху?

И что тут необычного? Все более чем стандартно. Ида. показывай код как пытался решить иначе рискуешь закрытием вопроса.

@SeVlad что конкретно в этой форме стандартно, кроме двух border-radius внизу?

@andreymal не так - что конкретно "не стандартно"?

@SeVlad на такое можно очень легко ответить — всё. И обратное вы не докажете, пока не расскажете, что конкретно тут стандартно и каким конкретно стандартным образом реализуется

@andreymal см, я тоже так могу: "стандартно" (обычно) тут всё. И обратное вы не докажете, пока не расскажете, что конкретно тут стандартно

@SeVlad я должен доказывать ваше утверждение? Вы как школу закончили с таким уровнем логических рассуждений?) Если вы утверждаете, что это всё стандартным образом реализуется — вот вы своё утверждение и доказывайте путём демонстрации этих самых стандартных способов. До тех пор считаем, что стандартным способом реализовать нельзя (иначе бы вы это уже с лёгкостью сделали вместо часового молчания)

(особенно смешно это всё на фоне отсутствия внятных определений для слов «стандартно» и «обычно»)

например как то так...


#y {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 25% 25% 5% 5% / 45% 30% 5% 5%;
  padding: 35% 5% 5% 5%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 50% 10%, transparent 0%, transparent 350%, gray 350%, gray 600%, green 900%);
  /* прозрачный круглешок (дырка). подробнее там:
  https://webref.ru/css/value/radial-gradient
  */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black) drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
  aspect-ratio: 2/1; /* !!!!!!!!!!! фиксация пропорций блока(условная
     - пока в нём хватает места под содержимое)*/
}

#y:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/favicon.ico?v=92117f9cb35c);
  border: 3px solid violet;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -22%;
  left: 24%;
}

#x {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  padding: 5em 1em 0 1em;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue, violet, brown, orange, pink, silver, lime, aqua)
}
<div id='x'>
  <div id='y'>
    йцукен
  </div>
</div>



с подбором более подходящих размеров и форм думаю справитесь
форму "вилки" менять тут: #y{border-radius: * * 5% 5% / * * 5% 5%;}

ну или можно почитерить с clip-path
